Install Python packages in Fedora 40 ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError
I am working in an virtual environment in Ubuntu 24.04 using python 3.12.3. The working directory is automatically synced on the cloud. Now, I installed Fedora 40 on my laptop (another PC) with a python version of 3.12.4.
I tried to run a couple of things but I realized that the system does not see some packages installed.
Therefore I ran this command:
pip install -r requirements.txt --user

However, I have got this error:
Processing /builddir/build/BUILD/libselinux-3.6/src (from -r requirements.txt (line 190))
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/builddir/build/BUILD/libselinux-3.6/src'

Do you have any idea, how can I solve this problem?

I found out a workaround that worked for me. I removed the lines from requirements.txt that caused this error and I could install all the packages.
